# How do I access the current context inside a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

If I have a function like this:

```
function doSomething(opt)
{
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
doSomething({a: 234, b: 567});
```

Is there a Javascript equivalent of the PHP extract() function so that I could do this:

```
function doSomething(opt)
{
    extract(opt);

    alert(a); // 234
    alert(b); // 567
}
```

The with() statement is not recommended any more and using the 'this' variable accesses the global scope - not the functions scope.

UPDATE:

Currently I'm doing the extraction manually like this:

```
function doSomething (opt)
{
    var a = opt.a,
        b = opt.b;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)?

Comment: could declare your function like `function doSomething({a, b})`

Comment: what you are looking for is called destructuring. you can also do it like `{ a, b } = opt`

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu That's very close to what I'm after - is it an ES6 thing?

Comment: [see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructuring is one approach. Below is another approach.

JavaScript has a concept called Rest parameters.... collect rest of the parameters in an array. What does that mean?

```
function doSimething(...items) {
     items.forEach(() => {
        // you can do stuff with each of the items.
    });
}
```

You can call it
doSimething(1);
doSomething(3,5,h);

This approach could help you make the function be more generic and used in more places.

[Additional information on JavaScript rest / spread parameters](https://www.google.com/amp/s/scotch.io/bar-talk/javascripts-three-dots-spread-vs-rest-operators543/amp)

Comment: I think this would be best for what I was after - though due to browser share I've decided to stick with an ES5 compatible solution. Which is a shame because this would be perfect for what I want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ES6 destructuring:

```
function doSomething({a, b})
{
    alert(a);
    alert(b);
}
```

Or

```
function doSomething(opt)
{
    const {a, b} = opt;
    alert(a);
    alert(b);
}
```

Comment: Interesting note on this: I've now been looking up browser market share and IE11 still shows roughly 5-7% depending on the region. And with this browser not supporting destructuring (AFAIK) and my software being publicly usable on all types of website - I think I'll stick to the old fashioned method, like that shown in the question, in order to preserve BC. Thanks though.